# Mocha not running all tests in suite in parallel

Tags: mocha.js

I have a test suite consisting of around 100 UI scenario tests that I am running with Mocha. When I run the suite in parallel (using the `--parallel` flag), the number of tests that are run is inconsistent and fluctuates. For instance, it might be 87 tests in one run and 94 in the next. Limiting the number of parallel jobs to for instance 10 (using the `--jobs` option) seems to mitigate the problem. However, this feels like a workaround rather than addressing the root cause. Thus, I am wondering what the reason is that Mocha runs a fluctuating number of tests in parallel mode (often not the entire suite), and how this issue can be addressed properly?

I am using version 8.1.1 of Mocha, and mocha-trx-reporter at 3.3.1 to report the test results. I do not use any options other than `--recursive` (to run the test suite) and `--parallel`.

Comment: Any solutions to this?